# How can I use a command output as a input string in the command "sed -i '10istring' a.txt"

Tags: batch-file, sed, replace

I have 2 files.

a.txt

> hi
>
> hello
>
> bye

b.txt

> apple
>
> banana
>
> grape

Every day I have to replace line 2 of a.txt to line 3 of b.txt
So Result should be

a.txt

> hi
>
> grape
>
> bye

**The contents of both files are everyday changed by other logic
So I cannot simply search pattern, 
but the line# that I should replace is never changed**

So far, I have got some "sed" command like below

```
$> sed -i '2d' a.txt

$> sed -i '2i**grape**' a.txt
```

This command will provide me the result I want, but in the "**grape**" part,
I want to use command output like this

```
$> sed -n 3p b.txt
```

So, the pseudo command should be like

```
$> sed -i '2i**sed -n 3p b.txt**' a.txt
```

The approach that I am thinking is possible? or Do I have a wrong approach?
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed` please try the following:

```
sed -i "2c $(sed -n 3p b.txt)" a.txt
```

Result:

```
hi
grape
bye
```

- The inner command `sed -n 3p b.txt` extracts the 3rd line of `b.txt`.
- The command substition `$(command)` is substituted by the command output.
- Then the line3 of b.txt is used as a replacement text for the `c` command.

Comment: @StevenLim Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. If you feel my answer solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Class assignment? If so... make sure you understand it all!
This will do what you asked for in pure bat. All additional lines except blank lines will be copied too.
This won't work if there are ! or other special characters in files a and b.

```
@echo off
if exist Newb.txt del Newb.txt /F /Q
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a LineA=0
set /a LineB=0

for /F "delims=" %%B in (b.txt) do (
   set /a LineB+=1
   if !LineB! equ 3 (
      for /f "delims=" %%A in (a.txt) do (
         set /A LineA+=1
         if !LineA! equ 2 (echo(%%B>>Newb.txt) else (echo(%%A>>Newb.txt)
      )
   goto :Done
   )
)

:Done
endlocal
```

Comment: thank you for your knowledge, I will definitely try this out!

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, you can do the following:

```
$a = Get-Content a.txt
$b = Get-Content b.txt
$a[1] = $b[2]
$a | Set-Content a.txt
```

A less readable one-liner would be something like

```
$a = gc a.txt; $a[0],(gc b.txt)[2],($a | select -skip 2) | sc a.txt
```

---

The PowerShell commands can be called in a batch file also. Set your batch file contents like the following and then just run the batch file in cmd:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "$a = Get-Content a.txt;$b = Get-Content b.txt;$a[1] = $b[2];$a | Set-Content a.txt"
```

Comment: thank you.
What about in bat?
Actually I am testing on powershell, but the script work on bat

Comment: @StevenLim you can call powershell from a batch file. I posted an example.